# In a 52-card deck, 3 cards are drawn. Calculate the probability of obtaining at least 1 ace.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, computational-mathematics, card-games

I have a problem with defining the events in probaility like for this example.

In a 52-card deck, 3 cards are drawn. Calculate the probability of obtaining at least 1 ace.

I dont understand How to seperate the events
As for this example I multiplied the choice of an ace card among the four ace type cards I multiplied it by all the combinations of choosing 2 remaining cards among 51 cards and then I divided the whole by the choice of 3 cards among 52.

I would like to understand my mistake I know the solution is to use ***1-p(a)***

Comment: You are computing P(exactly one ace) whereas you need to compute 1- P(no ace)

Comment: By choosing one ace and any two other cards, you are counting $A\spadesuit + (A\clubsuit, K\heartsuit)$ as distinct from $A\clubsuit + (A\spadesuit, K\heartsuit)$.

Comment: @trueblueanil I don't think the OP is computing P(exactly one ace). He's taking events with multiple aces into account. The issue here is an *over counting* of these events.

Comment: @AndreasLenz: You're right,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you are finding the probability of getting exactly one ace.

If we solve using your method, you need to evaluate:

P(exactly one ace) +P(exactly two aces)+P(exactly three aces) which is the same as 1-P(no ace)

Comment: The method used by the OP does *not* result in the probability of getting exactly one ace. Picking from the remaining 51 cards can give more aces. The essential mistake is counting possibilities more than once.

Answer (score 1):

$P(at\ least\ one\ ace)=1-P(no\ ace)=1-\dfrac{^{48}C_3}{^{52}C_3}$
In your attempt, you found out $P(exactly\ one\ ace)$. You also need to consider 2 aces, 1 other card and 3 aces.
In total you get $={^4C_1}*{^{48}C_2}+{^4C_2}*{^{48}C_1}+{^4C_3}$
Divide this by $^{52}C_3$ to get the desired probability. Actually, the compliment method is simpler.

Comment: But  The two remaining cards I take from the 51 cards so I take into consideration the two other aces

Comment: @MouhKramo If you take the remaining cards from 51/50/49 cards, you have no control over how many aces you choose. You need to take cases of exactly one/two/three aces, so choose from non-ace i.e. 48 cards.

Comment: This is not really an answer to the question. The OP is only eager to know what is wrong with his method.